# split image in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

this is my code for split the image into 9 pieces

```
                imgs = new Bitmap[3, 3];
                int width, height;
                width = _thePicture.Width / 3;
                height = _thePicture.Height / 3;
                for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
                    {
                        // Create the sliced bitmap
                        imgs[x,y] = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(_thePicture, x * width, y * height, width, height);
                    }
                }

                _img1.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 0]);
                _img2.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 0]);
                _img3.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 0]);
                _img4.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 1]);
                _img5.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 1]);
                _img6.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 1]);
                _img7.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 2]);
                _img8.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 2]);
                _img9.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 2]);
```

this will crop the image and inserted into matrix array of bitmaps.
the problem is user takes an image in portrait mode and when app split the image its in landscape form and its not in equal pieces.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i did fix the size i changed the height to be equal with width so i can have equal pieces. but still have the problem portrait how can i set the photo to be portrait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is user takes an image in portrait mode and when app split the image its in landscape form and its not in equal pieces.

You need to give an indicator when user is taking pictures in portrait mode (let's say `isPortrait`). And when in portrait mode, you can rotate the Bitmap before splitting the image:

```
//set isPortrait=true if user take picture in portrait mode
private async void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
    //rotate the image if user take the picture in portrait mode
    if (isPortrait)
    {
          thisPicture = RotateBitmap(_thisPicture, 90);
    }
    SplitImage(_thisPicture);
}
public  Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int degree)
{
    int w = bitmap.Width;
    int h = bitmap.Height;

    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.SetRotate(degree);

    return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}
private void SplitImage(Bitmap _thePicture)
{
    Bitmap[,] imgs;

    imgs = new Bitmap[3, 3];
    int width, height;
    width = _thePicture.Width / 3;
    height = _thePicture.Height / 3;

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
        {

            // Create the sliced bitmap
            imgs[x, y] = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(_thePicture, x * width, y * height, width, height);
        }
    }

    _img1.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 0]);
    _img2.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 0]);
    _img3.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 0]);
    _img4.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 1]);
    _img5.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 1]);
    _img6.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 1]);
    _img7.SetImageBitmap(imgs[0, 2]);
    _img8.SetImageBitmap(imgs[1, 2]);
    _img9.SetImageBitmap(imgs[2, 2]);
}
```